# PHP verification mail templates?

Tags: php, email

I was developing a site and its like 80% done and I am still working on it - the problem right now I am facing is client is asking me to show him a verification mail is sent when user get register with a link to verify the account - so despite decorating it I was searching for some ready made template that are already converted in PHP mail as I am new to php as well - But so far I have not found any ? can any body help me finding them online ? or they are not available over internet and I have to decorate the mail my self ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code

Comment: "decorating" the mail yourself shouldn't be very hard. However, I recommend using table layouts, as css is treated unpredicatably across mail clients. Just create an HTML file, lay out a template using tables and inline css (again, unfortunate).

Comment: I am not talking about in liners ! I am talking about pre-made templates !

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with a template?

If it is about the design, then you can send the email as html so you can format it anyway you want.

There are very good mailing scripts like [phpmailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) and [swift mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

You can also check [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/) and [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/).